# Передать дополнительные параметры в контроллер Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Возник вот какой вопрос. Пусть объявлен маршрут вида:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', [TestController::class, 'index']);
```

Согласно документации, в реализации `TestController` в методе `index` мне нужно прописать аргумент `$user`, и параметр из URI свяжется с аргументом метода.

Но я хотел бы как-то в объявлении данного маршрута передать еще и параметры в виде пар, к примеру `['locale' => 'ru', 'place' => 'dev']`. Как это можно сделать, не используя `{параметр}` в URI?

Comment: чем обычный request не подходит?

Comment: Если мне нужно будет `post` - он тоже подойдет? Хотя ... тут больше формальный вопрос "как передать параметры".

Comment: всё равно не понимаю. При чём тут метод, да хоть delete. в методе контроллера всегда доступна переменная `Request $request` в ней всегда все параметры которые передали, в данном случае у вас будет урл вида `/users/1?locale=ru&place=dev` при гет запросе и в $request будут эти значения. В чём траблы то не пойму?

Comment: добавьте на форму тег `a` и укажите эту ссылку и в контроллере dd($request->all())

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать куки или get параметры
http://site/users/1?locale=ru&place=dev